# Lightopenid, Gmail Auth, show popup instead of fullpage form

Tags: lightopenid

I'm using lightopenid for authentication to gmail.

Found [here](http://gitorious.org/lightopenid/lightopenid/blobs/master/openid.php):

The default way of presenting the login page for gmail is the full page version.  But I have noticed other websites showing a "popup version" and in the URL is

`&ltmpl=popup`

I've looked through the code and can't see a way of adding some custom options to the auth URL string.

Has anyone managed to do this?

```
    try 
    {
        $lightopenid = new Lightopenid;
        $lightopenid->required = $required_attr;

        if(!isset($_GET['openid_mode'])) 
        {
            $ui = "&openid.ns.ui=" . urlencode('=http://specs.openid.net/extensions/ui/1.0') . "&openid.ui.mode=popup";

            $lightopenid->identity = 'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id';               
            redirect($lightopenid->authUrl() . $ui, 'refresh');
        }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `$openid->authUrl()` returns an url, adding an option to it isn't too hard.

As far as I know, this is the correct way to do it:

```
$ui = "&openid.ns.ui=" . urlencode('http://specs.openid.net/extensions/ui/1.0') . "&openid.ui.mode=popup"
header('Location: ' . $openid->authUrl() . $ui);
```

Comment: I'm looking at functions authUrl_v1 and authUrl_v2.  I can't see where to put the code you mention.  Can you please give me a more verbose code.  Thanks

Comment: You're looking in the wrong place. Look at example.php, where authUrl() is used. If you're already using LightOpenID, you also have a line like `header('Location: ' . $openid->authUrl());` and you should modify that line to the code I posted above.

Comment: nope, still not working.  I have updated my question to show you what I am doing.

Comment: Ok, I've made a typo which I missed earlier. Try removing the '=' in urlencode(), so that it encodes only an url. Updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: @Mewp hi frieds... this is not opening in new window.... its opening in same window.... guide me